# Copying a file to every users directory (Win 7)

Tags: c#, vb.net, exe

I need to copy a file to every users directory, eg. (c:\Users\User1\Documents), (c:\User2\Documents), etc.

Right now I have this for copying files to one user, but not all:

```
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\LoggedHDir")) Then

        Dim myHiddenDir As DirectoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\LoggedHDir")
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\LoggedHDir")
        myHiddenDir.Attributes = (FileAttributes.Directory Or FileAttributes.Hidden)

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\LoggedHDir\rundllx86.exe")) Then

            objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            objFSO.CopyFile("C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\rundllx86.exe", "C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\LoggedHDir\rundllx86.exe")

        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Is this all on just one computer?  Or all computers in a domain?  What's the list of users?

Comment: @intracept  think it may be on a domain, but lets pretend it's not, for learning.

Comment: Well the way to do it on a domain is super easy (You can make a group policy object for it that would copy the file next login) if not using a domain its not so easy.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Can you explain how to do that in an answer, please

Comment: You said it's not a domain, and its not programming related either, its more IT setup. Go look up a tutorial on how to use Active Directory and Group Policy Objects to do a one time file copy and ask any questions you have on how to do it on the SuperUser or ServerFault sister sites.